# Center the map according to the layer filter result in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, layers

I have a layer in OpenLayers (version 5) that is only shown when the user types four values: codigo_setor, codigo_quadra, codigo_lote and if you want to show only the searched lot or the whole block, referring to the searched lot.

After typing the values, click on a button, which will create the layer with the filters:

```
var my_layer;

function setLayerLoteFiscal(codigo_setor, codigo_quadra, codigo_lote, show){    

    if (show){
        my_layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            name: 'my_layer', 
            visible: true,
            style: my_style,
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
                url: function(extent) {
                  return urlGeoserver +'wfs?service=WFS&' +
                      'version='+versionGeoserver+'&request=GetFeature&typename=geo:MY_LAYER&' +
                      '&outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
                      'CQL_FILTER=COD_SETOR = '+codigo_setor+' and COD_QUADRA='+codigo_quadra+'&' +
                      'all=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';
                },
                strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all
            })
        });
    }else{
        my_layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            name: 'my_layer', 
            visible: true,
            style: my_style,
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
                url: function(extent) {
                  return urlGeoserver +'wfs?service=WFS&' +
                      'version='+versionGeoserver+'&request=GetFeature&typename=geo:MY_LAYER&' +
                      '&outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
                      'CQL_FILTER=COD_SETOR = '+codigo_setor+' and COD_QUADRA = '+codigo_quadra+' and COD_LOTE='+codigo_lote+'&' +
                      'all=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';
                },
                strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all
            })
        });
        
            
    }
    return my_layer     

}

setLayerLoteFiscal(value_codigo_setor, value_codigo_quadra, value_codigo_lote, show) 
map.addLayer(layer_cadastro_lote_fiscal_busca)
//here: I would like to show it in a certain zoom, centered by the layer
```

I tested to check if there are features on the layer, but it returns 0. This was the code I tested, but it didn't work.

```
if (my_layer.getSource().getFeatures().length > 0) {
    map.getView().fit(my_layer.getExtent(), map.getSize());
}else alert('0')
```

What is wrong? I am not able to center on the map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will be no features until the source has loaded.  In later version there is a `featuresloadend` but for OpenLayers 5 you can set a listener for a `change` event before adding the layer.  Also you need the source extent, not the layer extent.

```
var source = my_layer.getSource();
source.once('change', function() {
  map.getView().fit(source.getExtent(), map.getSize());
});
map.addLayer(my_layer);
```